# NO DUPLICATE (Group by) Field 1 loop with field 2 in horizontal line

Tags: php, mysql, loops, group-by

Assuming I have table called "dp"

```
Year      | Month     | Payment|  Payer_ID | Payment_Recipient |
2008/2009 | July      | 100000 |     1     |        John       |
2008/2009 | August    | 200000 |     1     |        Jane       |
2009/2010 | August    | 150000 |     1     |        Jane       |
2009/2010 | September | 175000 |     1     |        John       |
```

In mysql view :

```
Year      |  July  | August | September | 
2008/2009 | 100000 | 200000 |    0      |
2009/2010 |    0   | 150000 |  175000   |
```

**I need output like this in my php page :**

```
    Year      |       July     |      August   |     September | 
    2008/2009 | 100000 | John  | 200000 | Jane |    0   |   -  | 
    2009/2010 |    0   |   -   | 150000 | Jane | 175000 | John |
```

I use some of this code :

```
    $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT
   year
 , SUM(IF(Month='July', Payment, 0)) As 'July'
 , SUM(IF(Month='August', Payment, 0)) As 'August'
 , SUM(IF(Month='September', Payment, 0)) As 'September'
FROM 
 dp
WHERE 
 Payer_ID = 1
GROUP BY
 Year";



    <?php do { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['year']; ?></td>
          <td><?php 
          $monthfilter=$row_Recordset1['month'];
          $valuefromfilter=$row_Recordset1['payment'];
          if ($monthfilter == 'July')
              {
              echo $valuefromfilter;
              }
              else
              {
              echo "<center>";
              echo "<font color=red><b>0</b></font>";
              echo "</center><br>";
              }
           ?></td>
          <td>script for august</td>
          <td>script for september</td>
                  </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

and it ended up like this :

```
    Year      |  July  | August | September | 
    2008/2009 |    *   |   *    |    *      |
    2009/2010 |    *   |   *    |    *      |
```

- = Undefined Index ....

Any solution for output in php page ?

Comment: Side note you should use PDO or MySQLi_* functions, PHP will stop supporting mysql_* functions in the future..

Comment: @RaymondNijland it's for learning use only and still using old Xampp server, but I'll learn it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doens't support PIVOT so you need to use an workaround

**Note you need to add an SUM rule for every month**

```
SELECT
   Year
 , SUM(IF(Month='July', Payment, 0)) As 'July'
 , SUM(IF(Month='August', Payment, 0)) As 'August'
 , SUM(IF(Month='September', Payment, 0)) As 'September'
FROM 
 dp
WHERE 
 Payer_ID = 1
GROUP BY
 Year
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37cd5/11

**Note for an large table you should use this index on (Payer_ID, Year) to remove the need for an temporary table and an sorting pass**

**Edit check the query below this will make the PHP client code very easy**

```
SELECT
   'Year'
 , 'July'
 , 'August'
 , 'September'
UNION ALL
SELECT
   Year
 , SUM(IF(Month='July', Payment, 0)) As 'July'
 , SUM(IF(Month='August', Payment, 0)) As 'August'
 , SUM(IF(Month='September', Payment, 0)) As 'September'
FROM 
 dp
WHERE 
 Payer_ID = 1
GROUP BY
 Year
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37cd5/13

**Note for an large table you should use this index on (Payer_ID, Year) to remove the need for an temporary table and an sorting pass**

Comment: yes, that's what i need thank you, now how to input it on my loop in my table php?

Comment: is there anyway to convert it to php variable so I can input it on my php view table

Comment: and by the way, if there are 'recipient' column (there are 2 recipient data that different for each month payment)  in 'dp' how to put recipient (based on recipient that receive the payment)  in sum(if command?

Comment: @user2966087 recipient column comment should be in an new question because the PIVOT workaround will be different, so this can confuse readers..

Comment: thanks, can you show me how to convert it to variabel so i can input it in my table (html table view)

Comment: @user2966087 if these months are fixed you can just loop... if not you need nested loops so you can dynamic handle the label (array key) and sum (array key)

Comment: yes, it's fixed, can you show me where the part that I need to change in my loop script above?